# Exporting data into excel via SSIS - package on server ignores named range

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-2008

I am trying to insert data into Excel file using SQL Server Integration Services. Everytime I have to create new excel file from template and fill two tables in one sheet, where first table starts on row 2 (data must start from 3 row), and second table starts on row 7 (data must start from 8 row). So, I created template excel file with two named ranges, in SSIS I created two Excel Destination Tasks and used named ranges as destination.

Everything perfectly works on my computer. I can run my package (in 32-bit mode), new excel file from template is created with filled properly tables.

Great, but it doesn't work properly on server. I created job that runs package with 32-bit option checked, added parameters and saved template on server. If I run job, it ends successfully, but excel file is not filled correctly. Whole saved data starts from row 2 (from both tables) and data from first table is overwritten by data from second table. It somehow ignores named ranges.

I tried another method without named ranges, that is, in Excel Destination Task I chosed SQL Command in "Data access mode" and write query `SELECT * FROM [Sheet$A2:N2]`, but same history. Works locally, but not on server.

I downloaded package and template file from server and ran on my computer and everything worked properly...

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: I find exporting to excel is easier when done via ssrs vs ssis

Comment: @KeithL I am not sure if I am able to do it, but thanks for idea. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps how I managed to export data to Excel starting from 7-th row. For this example, assume you export 4 columns. Caveat - it works on SSIS 2012+.

1. Create a template Excel file, with named range (say, `N1`) at `A6:D6` scoped for Workbook.
2. At Excel destination, open *Advanced Editor*, on Component Properties tab specify the following parameters - *AccessMode* choose `OpenRowSet`, *OpenRowset* type `N1`.
3. After that you have to map columns again at Excel destination.

Comment: Already done it. It works on my computer, but on server it looks like named range is ignored and all data is loaded starting from second row.

Comment: Please check Excel data provider. I have `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` at server side installed. Perhaps, you have it at PC and something other on the server.

Comment: It is installed. I think it wouldn't work at all without this excel data provider, but I can be wrong. Funny thing.

Comment: Strange. Created a test package, deployed to the server (SSIS 2014), tested it calling from either SSMS or from SQL Job. Both times output is Ok.
Do you output to Excel 2003 or Excel 2007 format?

Comment: Excel 2007. I am using SQL Server 2008. I finded wrokaround (just big select with many unions), but named ranges or SQL Command are much simpler and clearer.

My connection string: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=localization_of_excel_file;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0;HDR=YES"